# Adding background to ios app in xcode 6 using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am new to ios development so please forgive me. I am taking it step by step and I was wondering how would I make a image I want to be the background in the view controller so I can add on top of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically using swift here is the code:

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"))
```

Or you can create a uiimage and place your image in it:

```
let yourImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png")
let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
self.view.addSubview(imageview)
```

Comment: This code works but it zooms in and doesn't fit properly, what am I missing?

Comment: The size of "yourImage.png" should be the exact size of the view.
Pattern image takes the color of every point of image and place it as it is in view. So doesn't adjust the image to fit in view.

Comment: I edit my answer, and you can use the second choice to adjust your image.

Comment: If my answer helped you,could you upvote me if you want.

Comment: Says I need 15 Reputation to do it?

Comment: Oh ok, no prob then. Enjoy it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a UIImageView to your view controller's view. Assign your background image to the image view. You can do all this in the storyboard file.

Good luck!

Comment: @user3411711 if this answer worked for you, you can select the green checkmark to show that

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to adding a UIImageView and setting it as background.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg_image")
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)
}
```

Because I found the following code make the image a little blurry.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"))
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.